# install virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox

The provider 'virtualbox' that was requested to back the machine
'default' is reporting that it isn't usable on this system. The
reason is shown below:

> Vagrant could not detect VirtualBox! Make sure VirtualBox is properly installed.
> Vagrant uses the `VBoxManage` binary that ships with VirtualBox, and requires
> this to be available on the PATH. If VirtualBox is installed, please find the
> `VBoxManage` binary and add it to the PATH environmental variable.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: Please explain clearly and completely what you are trying to do and what is not working.